# storing data in secondary database

Tags: spring, hibernate, vert.x, nosql

Our application (java,spring, hibernate) uses postgress to store data.
We are looking to add an analysis engine to the application. I want to explore using a nosql db to run the analysis on. This is an attempt at learning the nosql a bit also to free the main application activity from performance penalty (as much as possible). 
So, I want the data changes to also synch to the nosql db (in addition to postgres). Any synch mechanism will affect the performance of the main data/transaction activity.

Is it a good idea to push the data changes to a message bus and free the main transaction as early as possible ? Can anyone point me to frameworks/technologies/ideas that address this issue of same data going to two different data stores.

Comment: The idea is to build a separate model of information tailored for analysis. Part of that information is the transnational data that goes to postgres. The analysis engine/model may be a different process. So, the question boils down to , how I can publish data changes in a manner that it adds as little performance penalty for the actual application transactions

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be sending data to a Postgres read replica and running your analytics queries on that. The performance impact is minimal and this would save a lot of time compared to alternative approaches.

Unless you really know what you are doing, I would avoid NoSQL for this kind of application. If your dataset is too big for a Postgres read replica, you might want to use Redshift, which is a columnar datastore that is optimized for types of analytics queries typically performed.

Comment: thank you schmatz. Say, I will try Redshift. How will synch Redshift with   whatever data changes done by my application. is that event bus idea good ? is pushing data through a message bus a good idea at all ?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing details of the application. I think in general, go for the simplest approach that fulfills the guarantees your application needs surrounding atomicity and performance. 

I'd recommend avoiding the Redshift approach unless you had a LOT of data and needed fairly strong performance on queries of that data as it isn't as friendly as a solution like Postgres.

Comment: thank you again for taking time to respond. if I go with the event bus approach, what are the more well known event busses are there. is vert.x a good one or guava event bus ?

Comment: No idea, I've never programmed in Java.